# Azure Python SDK to get usage details - UsageDetailsOperations Class

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am new to python.
I need to get the Usage details using python sdk.
I am able to do the same using the usage detail API.
But unable to do so using the sdk.
I am trying to use the azure.mgmt.consumption.operations.UsageDetailsOperations class. The official docs for UsageDetailsOperations 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-consumption/azure.mgmt.consumption.operations.usage_details_operations.usagedetailsoperations?view=azure-python#list-by-billing-period

specifies four parameters to create the object 
(i.e.client:Client for service requests,config:Configuration of service client,
serializer:An object model serializer,deserializer:An object model deserializer).

Out of these parameters I only have the client.
I need help understanding how to get the other three parameters or is there another way to create the UsageDetailsOperations object.

Or is there any other approach to get the usage details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is not designed to be created manually, you need to create a consumption client, which will have an attribute "usages" which will be the class in question (instanciated correctly).

There is unfortunately no samples for consumption yet, but creating the client will be similar to creating any other client (see [Network client creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/network?view=azure-python) for instance).

For consumption, what might help is the tests, since they give some idea of scenarios:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/fd643a0/sdk/consumption/azure-mgmt-consumption/tests/test_mgmt_consumption.py

If you're new to Azure and Python, you might want to do this quickstart:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/python-sdk-azure-get-started

Feel free to open an issue in the main Python repo, asking for more documentation about this client (this will help prioritize it):
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(I'm working at Microsoft in the Python SDK team).

Comment: Thank You. This solves my problem. I was trying to create the UsageDetailsOperations Class, but rather should use the Consumption client to get access to it.