# Python Azure SDK azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.operations VaultsOperations "VaultsOperations.__init__() missing required positional arguments' Error

Tags: python, azure-sdk-python, azure-resource-group

I'm trying to get the list of RecoveryServiceVaults by resource group name using Azure SDK package for Python **azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.** .

I coded as follows;

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservices import RecoveryServicesClient
from azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.operations import VaultsOperations 

subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]
tenant_id = os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"]
client_id = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"]
client_secret = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"]

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret) 

recovery_services_client = RecoveryServicesClient(credentials=credentials,subscription_id=subscription_id)

vault=VaultsOperations(recovery_services_client)
vaults_in_rg = vault.list_by_resource_group(rg_name)
for vault in vaults_in_rg: 
    print(vault)
```

And the Error I got is;

```
TypeError: VaultsOperations.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'config', 
'serializer', and 'deserializer'.
```

I don't know what variables I should provide to create VaultsOperations() class object.
Could you give some guidance ?

Does anyone know what kind of variable should be provided for object to be created?

Any opinions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to create an instance of `VaultsOperations` with the line `vault=VaultsOperations(recovery_services_client)`, but the initialisation of that class seems to require more arguments. You're passing only 1 of them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Python SDK to get usage details - UsageDetailsOperations Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292879/azure-python-sdk-to-get-usage-details-usagedetailsoperations-class)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52292879/azure-python-sdk-to-get-usage-details-usagedetailsoperations-class/52301403#52301403 for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [***Microsoft Documentation :-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices/azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.operations.vaultsoperations?view=azure-python)

---

> We should not instantiate this class directly. Instead, you should
> create a Client instance that instantiates it for you and attaches it
> as an attribute.

---

Also make sure to provide `Base url` in your code as below as you have not added the required parameter as mentioned [**`here`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-recoveryservices/azure.mgmt.recoveryservices.recoveryservicesclient?view=azure-python#constructor):

```
RecoveryServicesClient(credential: "TokenCredential", subscription_id: str, base_url: Optional[str] = None, **kwargs: Any)
```

For more information please refer to this [***GitHub samples***](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-python-management) .